# OpenCV - Python

Tags: python, opencv

```
img1 = cv2.imread('copy_lena.png')

imgGray1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB) #Converting the Image into Gray Scale

cv2.imshow('GrayScale_Image1',imgGray1)

cv2.waitKey(0)   #Delay. No. of Milliseconds for which we want to show our image window
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This code snippet is not working..........

-->The below error occur.

---

error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
13 img1 = cv2.imread('copy_lena.png')
14
---> 15 imgGray1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB) #Converting the Image into Gray Scale
16
17 cv2.imshow('GrayScale_Image1',imgGray1)

error: OpenCV(4.0.1) c:\ci\opencv-suite_1573470242804\work\modules\imgproc\src\color.hpp:259: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function '__cdecl cv::CvtHelper<struct cv::Set<1,-1,-1>,struct cv::Set<3,4,-1>,struct cv::Set<0,2,5>,2>::CvtHelper(const class cv::_InputArray &,const class cv::_OutputArray &,int)'

> Invalid number of channels in input image:
> 'VScn::contains(scn)'
> where
> 'scn' is 3

Answer (score 1):

Your code is converting the image from grayscale to color, not the other way around. Try replacing the second line with:

```
imgGray1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```